# Conditional save() on update?

Tags: django, django-models

I having a bit of a straight forward problem. None the less, I am having a hard time solving it.

I have one simplified model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False) 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    creation_date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)        

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.creation_date_time:
            existing_post = \
                self.author.post_set \
                .filter(
                    is_published=False, 
                    conversation=self.conversation) \
                        .exists()
            if existing_post:
                raise IndexError
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I want to check that:
**Every author can only have one non-published (draft) post.**

The current code checks this on creation of an instance but it gets quite complicated when the instance is updated and not created e. g. via the django admin.

It is important, however, that it is possible to update properties on the model regardless of `is_published`. Only creating two or more posts with `is_published=True` per user should raise an error.

Is there a way to do this that I am not seeing?

**EDIT:** Thanks to @nigel222 I could solve my problem. Here is my implementation:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.is_published == False:
        existing_post_uuids = \
            self.author.post_set \
                .filter(
                    is_published=False,
                    conversation=self.conversation) \
                        .values_list('uuid', flat=True)
        if len(existing_post_uuids) == 0 \
            or existing_post_uuids[0] == self.uuid:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise ValidationError('Users can only have one draft per conversation')
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: have you tried using the `pre_save` signal to add this custom logic?

Comment: Have you checked [ForeignKey.limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test at present doesn't investigate whether `exists()` refers to ourself, or not. What about

```
        existing_post_uuids = \
            self.author.post_set \
            .filter(
                is_published=False, 
                conversation=self.conversation) \
            .values_list( 'uuid', flat=True)
        if len( existing_post_uuids) > 1:
             # this shouldn't be possible ...
        elif len(existing_post_uuids) == 0:
             # creating - OK - none presently exists
        elif existing_post_uuids[0] == self.uuid:
             # updating
        else:
             # trying to create a second one
```

Answer (score 1):

An update will be saving an object with `self.pk` defined. A new object will be `self.pk is None`. Test that in your custom save:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is not None:
        return super().save( *args, **kwargs) # was an update

    # if still here we are saving a newly created object
    ...
```

Comment: hm, thanks. But thats not very helpful. Also, this doesn't work on a UUID fielt btw. Anyway, that part of the logic was not the problem discussed here.

Comment: Are you sure? Django internally needs to know the difference between update and create. Check the source for how it does it with a UUID. (If it's relevant).

Comment: hm, yes. So, pks are created in the database. This is why they don't exist when you first save an instance. Only when a model was saved to the DB at least once a pk exists. This is why the above logic works. UUIDs however are created by Django. This is why my example checks for `if not creation_date_time` since auto_now_add is also enforced on database level. But this just as a tip. As I've said. This part of the logic is not the problem.

Comment: See funnydman's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59968750/5246906 (which I am taking on trust)

Answer (score 0):

To check whether saving or updating is performing:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   is_new = self._state.adding
   if is_new:
       pass # adding new object.
   else:
       pass # updating the existing object.
   super().save( *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks also ... also not the relevant problem. If you play out the example above you'll see that its a bit more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution here is to override `AdminModel` [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method. You can then check if author have draft post and raise [Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/exceptions/#validationerror) error.